# How to get emoji to appear in the generated PDF using MigraDoc

Tags: c#, pdf, pdf-generation, emoji, migradoc

I'm trying to generate a PDF that contains some emojis but with no success.
To make it simple and reproduce-able here is the code:

```
    Document document = new Document();
    Section section = document.AddSection();


    Paragraph paragraph = section.AddParagraph();
    paragraph.AddFormattedText("   ♡", new Font("Segoe UI Emoji"));


    PdfDocumentRenderer pdfRenderer = new PdfDocumentRenderer(true);
    pdfRenderer.Document = document;
    pdfRenderer.RenderDocument();


    var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    var path = Path.GetTempFileName() + ".pdf";
    pdfRenderer.PdfDocument.Save(path);
    Process.Start(path);
```

But unfortunately empty rectangles appear instead:

```
��
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update: PDFsharp 6.0.0 and higher supports surrogate pairs and emojis will show.

This is a known limitation of PDFsharp 1.5. Surrogate pairs do not work yet and Unicode chars that require two 16-bit values (above 0xffff) will not show correctly.

See also:
https://github.com/empira/PDFsharp-1.5/issues/63

Comment: Now that we are half way through 2022, any chance that this has been fixed??  I.e. can PdfSharp now take text with emojis and include them in the save .pdf?

Comment: @Zeek2 It seems the proposed fix works for some emojis, but does not yet cover all possible cases. The code is not yet included in the official build.

Comment: @IlikedtheoldStackOverflow what's the proposed fix?  I don't see any

Comment: @NPearson Fixed the link.